# Misaligned indices

Tags: vertical-alignment

Why aren't the `$K$` and `$\chi$` vertically aligned in the following example and is there a simple workaround?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{D}_{K,\chi}$ 
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: The greek letter $\chi$ descends below the baseline, just like the English letters $q$, $y$, etc.